# how to open a socket in vscode-ws-jsonrpc

Tags: node.js, websocket, json-rpc

I'm checking vscode-ws-jsonrpc documentation and on the server side I see this line

```js
const socket: rpc.IWebSocket; // open the web socket
```

how do I open the websocket? what should go on that variable ?